# storing and retriving files from external storage: android

Tags: android, eclipse, android-activity

Hey guys i'm just a beginner to android programming! can some please tell me how to store a string of data to files in the external memory and how to retrieve them in a simplified manner!I require a good way to do this lengthy code is not an issue!I would like to use this file storage for storing and retriving passwords

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you want to do that but there are 3 ways to save string:

1- Use [**SharedPreferences**](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html)

2- Save into a [**File**](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html)

3- Use [**Database**](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html)